# How to call an indexer on a C# class from PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get Powershell to call an indexer on my class. The class looks something like this (vastly simplified):

```
public interface IIntCounters
{
    int this[string counterName] { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IIntCounters
{
    public IIntCounters Counters { get { return this; } }

    int IIntCounters.this[string counterName]
        { get { ...return something... } }
}
```

If I new up this class I can't just use the bracket operator on it - I get an "unable to index" error. I also tried using get_item(), which is what Reflector shows me the indexer ultimately becomes in the assembly, but that gets me a "doesn't contain a method named get_item" error.

**UPDATE:** this appears specific to my use of explicit interfaces. So my new question is: is there a way to get Powershell to see the indexer without switching away from explicit interfaces? (I really don't want to modify this assembly if possible.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me (uses reflection):

```
$obj = new-object MyClass
$p = [IIntCounters].GetProperty("Item")
$p.GetValue($obj, @("counterName"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but it seems like it should work:

```
$obj = new-object MyClass
$counters = [IIntCounters]$obj
$counters['countername']
```

(OK, I played around a little and I no longer think this is likely to work, but it still may be worth a try.)

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much the same as $obj.Counters['countername']..not working. :(

Comment: The reason I thought it might work is that explicitly implemented interfaces are only accessable via a reference to the interface, not via a reference to the implementing class. Unfortunately, when you cast a class reference to an interface reference, PowerShell still looks at it as reference to the most-derived class.

Comment: Right, but calling 'Counters' returns an IIntCounters, which is a reference to the interface, and not the class. Your point is interesting about posh looking through the interface to the class itself, though. If it always reflects on references to find the true concrete object underneath then that might explain this issue. Hm..might be able to install new methods that wrap up the explicit interface indexers..